# Five stars of open data - example and review

Tags: publishing

(there may be a more suited SE site for this question so feel free to shift)

I have some data I'd like to make open to the public - It's synatesis of some related data retrived from freedom of infomation requests over the last year.

The data itself is at http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/joseph/domesday/Domesday-Scotland.csv or for fans of Excel, at http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/joseph/domesday/Domesday-Scotland.xlsx .  It's no more than a table with about five columns.

I'd like to make this properly *open* data, so I was looking at the [5 star deployment scheme for Open Data](http://5stardata.info/).  Much of which is fine but I'm confused towards the end and I could do with an explenation from people who know the answers.

So to get achieve the star levels I need:

1. "make your stuff available on the Web (whatever format) under an open license" trival - all I have to do is put the notes up on the page that will give the provance of the data.
2. "make it available as structured data (e.g., Excel instead of image scan of a table)"… done…
3. "use non-proprietary formats (e.g., CSV instead of Excel)" - done…
4. "use URIs to identify things, so that people can point at your stuff" - this is where I start to get a bit hazy - does this mean there should be an URI for every line in the table?
5. "link your data to other data to provide context" - this isn't massively clear to me - does this mean to give the provence of the data? One column of the data I've put out is a link to where the data came from - is that the sort of thing we're looking at?

Any and all information and answers welcome…

EDIT - or if anyone wants to recommend a place SE or other place to ask the question - that would be cool...

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:date]. Did you mean [tag:data]?

Comment: Yes, yes I did… Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following a couple of skype conversations, and a bit of a thing on twitter, I got a nice answer from a good guy.

From 3 to 4/5 star, use:

http://idi.fundacionctic.org/tabels/

Re licensing:

http://www.w3.org/TR/void/#license